# Eclipse WTP deployment of build path dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-wtp, jboss-tools

I have an Eclipse project that is dependent on other projects (Project Properties/Java Build Path/Projects), and these other projects export their own libraries (Project Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export).

Is there a way to get Eclipse WTP and/or JBoss Tools to include the dependent project's exported files in a deployment?

I can add the jars individually via the Deployment Assembly but I don't want to duplicate the configuration.

We currently use MyEclipse for this but we're trying to get away from it for other reasons.

Craig

Answer (score 7):

Let's say your projects are called "util" for the one that is included and "web" for the downstream one.

1. In util, go to Deployment Assembly page under project properties. Hit Add and select "Java Build Path Entries" option. Select jars that are on util project's build path that should packaged with it.
2. In web, go to Build Path page and remove dependency on util. That's not how you want that dependency setup.
3. Again in web, go to Deployment Assembly page and select Project option. Pick util on the next page. After add, you can see on the Deployment Assembly page an entry for util that you can expand to see everything else that will also be included.